# VSCode C/C++ output is going to the debug console instead of the terminal

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I have this issue on windows but when running it in WSL it's pushing stdio to terminal. I'd really like to fix this issue without using the code runner extension but almost all of the solutions I've seen do that. I even tried to use code runner to fix it but it didn't work. Any help? Lmk if you need to see any settings files ect

edit:
was asked for a minimal reproducible example for launch config.

```
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "C/C++: gcc.exe build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "FILEPATH",
        }
    ]
```

edit 2:
I noticed the issue appearing after turning on settings sync for my mac so I would guess its a setting somewhere there but I cant find it. ill post something on here if I find it.

Comment: show [mre] launch config

Comment: weird... you haven't set `"avoidWindowsConsoleRedirection": true`. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/9696

Comment: Nope just using the autogenerated config for gdb launch